# I want to make a calendar in which weekends are disabled as well as show only the data that I'm passing in the calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This script is not working for the Date Format `MM-dd-yyyy`. Please let me know if there is a option to fix it. I want to make it generic.

**My Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       debugger;
       var _dateFormat = '';
       _dateFormat = $("#hdnDtFormat").val();

       var dateArray = ("#hdnCollectionDate").val();
       var enabledDays = new Array();
       if (dateArray.length > 0) {
           enabledDays = dateArray.split(",");
           var _firstVal = enabledDays[0];
           var _LastVal = enabledDays[4];
           GetCalederLoad(_firstVal, _LastVal, _dateFormat);
       }
    });


    function GetCalederLoad(startDt, endDt, dtFormat) {
       if (dtFormat != undefined && dtFormat != "")
          dtFormat = dtFormat.toLowerCase();

          $("#drpNewCollectionDateSvc").datepicker({
               autoclose: true,
               clearBtn: true,
               startDate: startDt, // '(System.Web.Mvc.SelectList)(ViewData["CollectionDate"]).First();', //firstarrdate,
               endDate: endDt, // '(System.Web.Mvc.SelectList)(ViewData["CollectionDate"]).Last();',// lastarrdate,
               format: dtFormat,
               daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
               Default: false,
               beforeShowDay: function (Date) {
                  var curr_date = Date.toJSON().substring(0, 10);
               }
          });
     }
    </script>
```

I'm getting data from Server in the format of

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _dateFormat = '';
    _dateFormat = 'MM-dd-yyyy';
    var dateArray = '07/05/2016,07/06/2016,07/07/2016,07/08/2016,07/11/2016';
    var enabledDays = new Array(); enabledDays = dateArray.split(",");
    var _firstVal = enabledDays[0]; var _LastVal = enabledDays[4]; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not clear but there is no option named `format`. Correct name is [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat), e.g.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```